# WS02 GREG ERROR when deploying carbon archive

Tags: wso2

I am trying to upload a carbon archive in the registry. Everything seems to be OK when I add a new application, but the log show the following error:

```
An error occurred while determining the latest version of the resource at the given path:
/_system/governance/trunk/wsdls/.... (path to the wsld deployed)
org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Failed to obtain the user realm for tenant: -1
```

I log with the admin user and everything that should be upload is in the registry.

Any help?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce this with WSO2 G-Reg 4.1.1 but unable to reproduce it.

Please indicate the G-Reg version you have tried out this scenario.

When you upload the CAR file from Management Console, make sure to remove the previous version of the same CAR file before you upload the newer version.

This error seems to be related versioning.

Since you remove the previous version of the CAR file, the aforementioned suggestion will solve your problem.

Thanks and Regards,

Harshana

Comment: I think this does not happen when I upload a wsdl for the first time. When I remove a carbon app, I delete it and after that I remove the service and wsdl. Is this a correct way to do it? Should I keep the wsdl and services?

Comment: My registry version is 4.1.1 as well.

Comment: If you deploy the WSDL with CAR file, then when you remove/delete the CAR file, CAR file deployer takes care of undeploying of resources deployed with it. Therefore you don't need to explicitly go and delete them from the registry. 

When you do that, CAR deployer will be unable to perform its tasks and hence you might face some unpredicatable behavior. Therefore do not delete either WSDL or the service manually. Let the deployer to handle it.

Comment: Hi, I have test what you said with no success. I have uploaded to the registry a car file containing an wsdl. After deploying, I get a new wsdl in Metadata/wsdl. If I undeploy the carbon app, it is removed from the app list but the wsdl keeps in WSLD & schema remains in the WSDL list. Do I have miss any kind of configuration to the make the undeployer remove the wsdls?

Answer (score 0):

WSDLs are stored in the /_system/governance/../trunk/wsdl/.. location if you upload them via management console or upload the resource from Developer Studio Registry Browser.

But when you deploy a WSDL via a C-App, when creating the registry resource from Developer Studio, you specify a location to deploy. Hence the WSDLs deployed via C-Apps are deployed to this specified location but not the other location.

Therefore from your proxy service, you should refer the location you have mentioned to deploy your WSDL but not the default location.

Once you fix this, your Proxy service will work fine.

Thanks and Regards,

Harshana

Comment: I have checked that when you upload a wsdl containg a car file via management console the wsld file is placed in root folder. If I upload via car archive it is placed where I set it. Both cases, the wsld is processed by the system and the result is a new wsdl/schema metadata. When I undeploy the car app which has generated the new wsdl/schema it fails to remove the wsdl/schema metadata entry. When you say "you should refer the location you have mentioned to deploy your WSDL but not the default location.", do you mean the trunk/wsdl location or the one I place the wsdl?

Comment: I mean the one you place the WSDL file.

Whenever a WSDL is stored in the G-Reg, there is an handler to handle WSDL files and it is getting invoked and the metadata is generated. 

One more thing is that, if you are referring to this WSDL file from a proxy service, you need to upload this WSDL to ESB's registry but not the G-Reg. You can do this by changing the Server Role of your Registry Artifact in the C-App from Developer Studio.

Comment: We have just one greg for all components, so I upload the wsdl to the config folder in the esb. This means the wsdl is placed in the esbConfig folder of the greg. When I navegate through the config governace tree from esb to in the proxy wizard, I can not see the any wsdl but the ones placed in trunk folder. "wsld" means a file containing a wsdl, no matter the file extension. I have made some tests uploading a *.wsdl, *.xml, and a *.txt file with simple text. Text file is the only one I succeed in seeing it from the ESB. May it be a kind of filter to foce you to use the trunk wsdl?